# does ArgumentTransformationAttribute return Objects out of the Transform Method?

Tags: powershell

this is a class to transform a computername into a CimSession type:

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation ;
using namespace System.Net.NetworkInformation ;
using namespace Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure ;

enum Protocol {
    WsMan
    Dcom
}

class ComputernameTransformationAttribute : ArgumentTransformationAttribute {
    <# ValidateComputername #>
    
    hidden [CimSession] NewCimsession([string] $inputData){

        
        $Protocol = [Protocol]::WsMan -as [string] ;
        $CimSessionOption = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol $Protocol ;
        
        # [CimSession] $Cimsession = New-CimSession @Param
        [CimSession] $Cimsession = [CimSession]::Create($inputData, $CimSessionOption);

        return $CimSession;
    }

    # Transform() method is called whenever there is a variable or parameter assignment.
    [System.Object] Transform(
        [EngineIntrinsics]$engineIntrinsics, 
        [System.Object]$inputData
    ){
    
        return $($this.NewCimsession($inputData));
    }
}
```

i tried to test hier but the Transform method is not returning any object, just a splatted info i can't use.
am i doing something wrong hier ?
hier ist my test funtion:

```
function Get-ADComputerDescription {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    #[OutputType([GKMAdinfo])]
    param (
        # ComputerName
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        # [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Alias("CN","Machine","Name")]
        [ComputernameTransformation()]
        [string]$ComputerName
    )
    $ComputerName
    Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem -CimSession $ComputerName
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: You have a `[string]` type constraint on parameter `$ComputerName`, which argument transformation likely can't overcome. Try to remove the type constraint or use `[CimSession]` as the constraint.

Comment: You don't really need a `CimSession` for just this query, no point in using it but @zett42 has provided the right answer in his comment.

Comment: it's just a function i built for testing purpose. but i will need the [CimSession] ;)
thx.